# Gulp-Shell is not executing any commands

Tags: gulp, gulp-shell

I'm trying to execute something using `gulp-shell`. My `gulfile.js` contains the following content:

```
var gulp  = require('gulp'),
    shell = require('gulp-shell');

gulp.task('test', function() {
  shell(['echo test']);
});
```

Then I run it calling `gulp test`. This is the output I get:

```
Using gulpfile ~/gulpfile.js
Starting 'test'...
Finished 'test' after 2.62 ms
```

There's no output for my echo call.

I'm using an `Ubuntu 14 VM` that I connected to, using `Putty`.

Anyone got an idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's because it's not the good way to use gulp-shell.

Try this, as seen in the [gulp-shell README](https://github.com/sun-zheng-an/gulp-shell#usage).

```
var gulp  = require('gulp'),
    shell = require('gulp-shell');

gulp.task('test', shell.task([
    'echo test'
]));
```

Comment: Oh well.. that was easy, and I was bothering my head with it. But it seems rather inconsistent with the rest of the task definitions. Might want to elaborate what's the big difference? :-)

Comment: And is there a way to not make it strip colors away from the output?

Comment: That's just the way it works. I think it has something to do with the way gulp stream's data. I don't think there is a way for the colors to show, maybe try to put your commands in an external script file and launch that file with gulp-shell, just an idea.

Answer (score 4):

For the record, if you want to pipe gulp-shell, [per specified in the doc](https://github.com/sun-zheng-an/gulp-shell#user-content-usage):

```
gulp.task('myGulpTask', [], function() {
  return gulp.src('gulpfile.js', {read: false})
    .pipe(shell('echo "This works too"'));
});
```

Comment: This is now considered an anti pattern don't do this - https://github.com/sun-zheng-an/gulp-shell